# Worksheet_Change Event - Duplication Check, Ignore Blanks

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a VBA change event to look for duplicates in column C. The code below works but when i delete all values within the range, blanks are triggered as duplicates so i need to include a way to ignore duplicates from the code. Any ideas?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim cell As Range

    On Error GoTo ws_exit

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    With Target

        If .Column = 3 Then

            With .EntireColumn

                Set cell = .Find(What:=Target.Value, AFter:=.Cells(1, 1))
                If cell.Address = Target.Address Then

                    Set cell = .FindNext()
                End If

                If Not cell.Address = Target.Address Then

                    MsgBox "This Wall Reference already exists. Please ensure you have a unique reference identifier less than 20 characters in length", vbOKOnly
                End If
            End With
        End If
    End With

    ws_exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

I expect to be able to ignore blanks but sill have the VBA run a duplication check to return a msgbox only if a duplication is found.

Comment: I recommend to use `WorksheetFunction.CountIf` instead of `Find` to determine if it is a duplicate or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help K.Davis. I appreciate your time and effort.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Value = vbNullString Then Exit Sub
    Dim cell As Range

    On Error GoTo ws_exit

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    With Target

    If .Column = 3 Then

    With .EntireColumn

    Set cell = .Find(What:=Target.Value, AFter:=.Cells(1, 1))
    If cell.Address = Target.Address Then

    Set cell = .FindNext()
    End If

    If Not cell.Address = Target.Address Then

    MsgBox "This Glazing Reference already exists. Please ensure you have a unique reference identifier less than 20 characters in length", vbOKOnly
    End If
    End With
    End If
    End With

    ws_exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

First you must consider that `Target` is a range of multiple cells and not only one cell. Therefore it is necessary to use `Intersect` to get all the cell that are changed in column 3 and then you need to loop through these cells to check each of them.

Also I recommend to use `WorksheetFunction.CountIf` to count how often this value occurs if it is `>1` then it is a duplicate. This should be faster then using `Find`.

Note that the following code looks for duplicates in column 3 only if you want to check if a duplicate exists anywhere in the worksheet replace `CountIf(Me.Columns(3), Cell.Value)` with `CountIf(Me.Cells, Cell.Value)`

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim AffectedRange As Range
    Set AffectedRange = Intersect(Target, Me.Columns(3))

    If Not AffectedRange Is Nothing Then
        Dim Cell As Range
        For Each Cell In AffectedRange

            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Me.Columns(3), Cell.Value) > 1 Then
                MsgBox "This Wall Reference already exists. Please ensure you have a unique reference identifier less than 20 characters in length", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation
            End If

        Next Cell
    End If

End Sub
```

Instead of using VBA you could also use Conditional Formatting to highlight duplicates in red for example. Could be easier to archieve (use the `=CountIf` formula as condition). And also it will always highlight all duplicates immediately which makes it easy to determine them.

Comment: Thanks PEH. I cannot use conditional formatting as it is already being used for other requirements.